# Why is the word "triple" spelt with 1 p although tri is an open syllable?

Tags: etymology, orthography, syllables

**nipple** has a double p. 
**tripod** and **triangle** are pronounced tr/I/

Comment: 'Nipple' has double P because P is a part of stressed syllable. 'Tripod' has a single P because P is a part of unstressed syllable.

Comment: @herisson, These are just spelling irregularities in English.

Comment: Because English!

Comment: As noted, this is a random variation in English spelling. There are a lot of them, because **English spelling does not represent English pronunciation**. Therefore, you can't count on spelling being consistent with pronunciation. That's why you should learn spellings **and** pronunciation independently.

Answer (score 1):

Plenty of English words have a non-doubled consonant letter after a short vowel. The only time when you can expect consonant doubling to systematically apply after a short vowel is before certain suffixes (such as *-ing, -ed, -er, -est, -ist*).

But in a non-suffixed word like *triple,* there isn't an easy way to predict the spelling from the pronunciation or vice versa. The spelling "tripple" was used in the past; it happened to not survive up to the present in standard written English. When English spelling became more fixed, a lot of relatively unpredictable quirks like this became frozen (the spellings used in Samuel Johnson's dictionary were often adhered to by later writers). The fact that the French and Latin etymological sources, *triple* and *triplex,* have only a single P was possibly a factor.

Comment: And the wags' _trippple_ never caught on.

Comment: There is a difference between *trifle* and a word like *triffid,* though. (Cf *triple* and *tripping.*)